# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException (java selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

```
package main_files;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class main_downloader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.wait(1);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.wait(5);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

for some reason when I try to run this code it gives me this Error

```
1597445198205   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:7834
1597445198836   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileinTqzS"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
console.error: SearchCache: "_readCacheFile: Error reading cache file:" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
1597445201342   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 22663
1597445201445   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Aug 15, 2020 1:46:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at main_files.main_downloader.main(main_downloader.java:10)
```

i've tried some solutions but nothing worked !, could anyone help please !? Thx.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with the lines `driver.wait(1)` and `driver.wait(5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wait() function call must be called from Synchronized block to avoid this exception.
Do you want to sleep the main thread , if yes please use Thread.sleep() instead of wait() function call.